# Finding the range from an array - Recursive version

Tags: recursion

Here is my iterative algorithm. I want to write a recursive version
Make A an array of size n
Make min = infinity and make max = -infinity

```
For i from 0 to n-1

  If A[i] > max

    max = A[i]


  if A[i] < min

    min = A[i]

  Return max - min
```

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: What language? Or do you need just pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const range = (arr, min, max, i) => {
  if (i == arr.length) return [min, max];
  if (arr[i] > max) return range(arr, min, arr[i], i + 1);
  if (arr[i] < min) return range(arr, arr[i], max, i + 1);
};

console.log(
  range(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 99, 432, -123],
    Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    0
  )
);
```